# Cookie banner is not displaying as intended when using Hugo with Docsy theme

Tags: css, sass, hugo, docsy

I am developing a sample website using [Hugo](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo) static website generator by using the [Docsy](https://github.com/google/docsy) theme.

The website includes the `Cookie Banner` so I have added the same to my static website by referencing the approach mentioned from here: https://hugocodex.org/add-ons/cookie-consent/.

Ideally, I would like the banner to be visible something like this:

[image]

But currently its looking something like this:
[image]

When I have added it along with styles and `partials` its not looking like that. Maybe some style is messing up the child `cookie consent` styles but unable to figure out the same. Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

I have added my complete code in following github project:
https://github.com/Aravinda93/hugo-docsy-learn

I am quite new to Hugo and Docy so getting bit confused on the folder and file structure hence unable to figure out which parent style is messing up my `Cookie consent` modal. Can someone please help me with some suggestions?

I tried couple more things but still the cookie banner is not displayed as I intended it to be. Can someone please provide some suggestion?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/73609444/2397550

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hugo/Docsy: Cookie info banner is not displaying as intended due to CSS/SCSS mismatch/override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73609444/hugo-docsy-cookie-info-banner-is-not-displaying-as-intended-due-to-css-scss-mis)