# Hugo/Docsy: Cookie info banner is not displaying as intended due to CSS/SCSS mismatch/override

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, hugo, docsy

I am developing a simple website using the [Hugo](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo) static website generator and the [Docsy](https://github.com/google/docsy) theme. The website includes a simple information `Cookie Banner` so I have added the same to my static website by referencing the approach mentioned on: [Cookie consent | Hugo Codex](https://hugocodex.org/add-ons/cookie-consent/)

Ideally, I would like the banner to be visible like this:

[image]

But currently its looking something like this:
[[image]

I have added all styles and `partials` but still it didn't look as expected. Maybe some styles are messing up the child `cookie consent` styles but unable to figure out the same. Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

I have added my complete code to the following GitHub project:
https://github.com/Aravinda93/hugo-docsy-learn

I am quite new to Hugo and Docsy, so I am getting a bit confused about the folder and file structure, hence am unable to figure out which parent style is messing up my `Cookie consent` modal. Can someone please help me with some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was solved here: https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/cookie-banner-is-not-displaying-as-intended-when-using-hugo-with-docsy-theme/40332/7.

This should be removed:

```
font-size: s;
transform: translateY(100vh);
color: var(--color-warning);
background-color: var(--color-warning-bg);
width: 100%;
```

This should be added:

```
background: white;
border-color: white;
margin-left: -15px;
width: calc(100% + 30px);
```